# FLAnimatedImage multiple gif playback delay when using loop count - objective c

Tags: objective-c, animated-gif

I have a UIPageViewController that displays 5 gifs, one in each page.
FLAnimatedImage works great, there was only one drawback, there was nothing to set animation loop and so I used https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage/pull/60 to achieve that.

But another problem occurred after a gif completes and stops in one controller and I move to another controller and then return to the previous controller, the gif will start after a delay.

I'm not sure how to fix that. All the delays in the class FLAnimatedImages are related to the animation delays and not playback delays.

Here is an extract from the class FLAnimatedImage.m in the method `initWithAnimatedGIFData`:

```
                // Try to use the unclamped delay time; fall back to the normal delay time.
                NSNumber *delayTime = [framePropertiesGIF objectForKey:(id)kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime];
                if (!delayTime) {
                    delayTime = [framePropertiesGIF objectForKey:(id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime];
                }
                // If we don't get a delay time from the properties, fall back to `kDelayTimeIntervalDefault` or carry over the preceding frame's value.
                const NSTimeInterval kDelayTimeIntervalDefault = 0.1;
                if (!delayTime) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        FLLogInfo(@"Falling back to default delay time for first frame %@ because none found in GIF properties %@", frameImage, frameProperties);
                        delayTime = @(kDelayTimeIntervalDefault);
                    } else {
                        FLLogInfo(@"Falling back to preceding delay time for frame %zu %@ because none found in GIF properties %@", i, frameImage, frameProperties);
                        delayTime = delayTimesMutable[i - 1];
                    }
                }
                // Support frame delays as low as `kDelayTimeIntervalMinimum`, with anything below being rounded up to `kDelayTimeIntervalDefault` for legacy compatibility.
                // This is how the fastest browsers do it as per 2012: http://nullsleep.tumblr.com/post/16524517190/animated-gif-minimum-frame-delay-browser-compatibility
                const NSTimeInterval kDelayTimeIntervalMinimum = 0.02;
                // To support the minimum even when rounding errors occur, use an epsilon when comparing. We downcast to float because that's what we get for delayTime from ImageIO.
                if ([delayTime floatValue] < ((float)kDelayTimeIntervalMinimum - FLT_EPSILON)) {
                    FLLogInfo(@"Rounding frame %zu's `delayTime` from %f up to default %f (minimum supported: %f).", i, [delayTime floatValue], kDelayTimeIntervalDefault, kDelayTimeIntervalMinimum);
                    delayTime = @(kDelayTimeIntervalDefault);
                }
                delayTimesMutable[i] = delayTime;
            } else {
                FLLogInfo(@"Dropping frame %zu because valid `CGImageRef` %@ did result in `nil`-`UIImage`.", i, frameImageRef);
            }
            CFRelease(frameImageRef);
        } else {
            FLLogInfo(@"Dropping frame %zu because failed to `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex` with image source %@", i, _imageSource);
        }
    }
    _delayTimes = [delayTimesMutable copy];
    _frameCount = [_delayTimes count];
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution as a workaround was to change the UIPageController transition style to curl instead of scroll, so a new instance of the page content controller will always be created and the gifs will always be reloaded into memory.